Logging background processes with AWS X-Ray?
How can I log background operations with Amazon X-Ray?

I tried to create new Segment using Instance.BeginSegment
I also tried to create new Recorder and create Segment in it

I am not seeing any errors, and also I am not seeing any data logged.
I am using dotnet core SDK but I guess solution will be similar with any other SDK.

The solution is to use AWSXRayRecorderBuilder class, like this:
var xRayTracing = new AWSXRayRecorderBuilder()
    .WithContextMissingStrategy(Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Core.Strategies.ContextMissingStrategy.LOG_ERROR)
    .WithTraceContext(new AsyncLocalContextContainer())
    .Build();
.... 

You may also consider to fill HttmlInformation so it will be visible on Races list view in AWS Console:
var requestInformation = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["url"] = "BackgroundProcessor",
    ["method"] = message.State
};
xRayTracing.AddHttpInformation("request", requestInformation);
            

and an actual logging could be wrapped in try/catch/finally:
try
{
    // some actions here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    xRayTracing.AddException(ex);
    throw;
}
finally {
    xRayTracing.EndSegment(); 
}

